# Express server using default route, also serve API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The way I have this app set up, every request gets serviced by the same route that will do some JS serverside rendering:

```
server.use("*", (req, res) => {
    console.log(`from the server route: ${req.path}`)
    const context = {};
    const serverRenderedHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        React.createElement(
            StaticRouter,
            { location: req.url, context },
            React.createElement(AdminApp)
        )
    );

    if (context.url) {
        res.redirect(context.url);
    }

    res.write(template({ serverRenderedHTML }));
    res.end();
});
```

But, I would also like to use my express server as an api for some resources, routes set up like this:

```
//server.js
server.use("/api/products", productRoutes);

// products.js
router.get( (req, res) => {
    var productQuery = Product.find({})
    productQuery.exec(function(err, products){
        res.json(products)
    })
})
```

However, I am unable to hit the API, as all of my requests are getting picked up by that server.use function.

Is there any way to make sure that the routes under /api/ namespace are properly picked up? Should I just make a different server for the API?

Comment: Routes are matched in order so just put your more specific routes first before the `*` routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to include an argument for the route. **I had to change:**

```
router.get( (req, res) => ...
```

to

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => ...
```